# $6$ women and $4$ men wait in line. If their order in line is random, find the probability that all of the women are adjacent to one another.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My thoughts on the problem are that the number of ways the women can be adjacent to each other is $5!$ and the total number of arrangements for all the people is $10!$. Is this correct?

Comment: wwwwww mmmm ,m wwwwww m m m , m m wwwwww m m , m m m wwwwwww m , m m m m wwwwww, so 5!+ 5!+5!+5!+5!= 5*(5!)

Comment: total arrangements for them is 10!

Comment: The easy way to solve this question is to start with $1$ man and $2$ women.

Comment: The probability is zero. If the women are in a line, it is impossible for them all to be adjacent to one another; each woman will be adjacent to at most $2$ other women.

Comment: Zero.  The women can't all be adjacent to each other if they're standing sequentially in a line.

Comment: how did this question get into the hot questions list?

Comment: Sounds like a math homework question...

Comment: Are at least two women married to two of the men in line?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly you should edit "adjacent to each other" to "occupying consecutive positions" or something to that effect. I did not edit because I wasn't sure what you are asking, but the current question's wording is a bit confusing and, strictly speaking, contradictory as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Some hints: $10$ people can be arranged in a line in $10!$ ways. Four men and a bench can be arranged in $5!$ ways. Six women can be placed on the bench in $6!$ ways.

Answer (score 16):

Total number of arrangements was correctly determined as $10!$.

The number of ways the $6$ women can all stand next to each other are easily seen through the following:

$W_{1} W_{2} W_{3} W_{4} W_{5} W_{6}$ __ __ __ __

__ $W_{1} W_{2} W_{3} W_{4} W_{5} W_{6}$ __ __ __

__ __ $W_{1} W_{2} W_{3} W_{4} W_{5} W_{6}$ __ __

__ __ __ $W_{1} W_{2} W_{3} W_{4} W_{5} W_{6}$ __

__ __ __ __$W_{1} W_{2} W_{3} W_{4} W_{5} W_{6}$

So, we have $5$ ways for the women to be next to each other and $4!$ ways to arrange the men. Next, we need to determine how many different ways the women can be arranged, which is $6!$

Thus, the total number of ways the women can be next to each other is: $(5\cdot 4!)(6!)$

Probability all women are adjacent: $\large\frac{5!6!}{10!}$

Comment: The $5!$ comes from the fact that while the women can be arranged in $5$ ways, you still need to take the men's arrangements into account. With four seats left, the men can be arranged in $4!$ ways, and $5*4!=5!$ ways for everyone to be arranged so that the women are next to each other. But thanks for the $6!$ bit, that's the part I was missing!

Answer (score 10):

Choosing $6$ places out of $10$ can be done in $\binom{10}{6}$ ways.

Choosing $6$ places out of $10$ under the extra condition that they are adjacent can be done in $5$ ways.

This leads to a probability of: $$5\times\binom{10}{6}^{-1}=\frac{5}{210}=\frac{1}{42}$$

Answer (score 3):

There are $10!$ arrangements in total. The number of arrangements where women are adjacent is that $5!\times 6!$. So the probability you are looking for is the ratio of these two.

Answer (score 3):

The total number of arrangements in which women are next to each other is $5!$ **times** number of ways in which they can be permuted among themselves which is $6!$. So, the probability is $\dfrac{5!6!}{10!}$

Answer (score -1):

((women factorial - men factorial) $\times$ possible permutations)/Total possible arrangements irrespective of order factorial

((6!-4!)$\times$5)/10! = 3600/3628800 = 0.00099206
or a 0.0992% probability

Answer (score -1):

this is $$1- \frac{\text{number of ways in which they are together}}{\text{total possibilities}} = 1-\frac{5!}{10!}$$

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). You can [edit] your post to improve its presentation.